# utf8 representation as normal text

Tags: php, utf-8, utf

```
$text = "\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0";
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $text);
var_dump($text); //Тайна - good
$text = file_get_contents('log.txt');
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', trim($text));
var_dump($text); // \xd0\xa2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 - bad
```

Why if string `\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0` was read from file `iconv` did not work and how to fix it ?

Comment: Check server settings. (php.ini and mbstring)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string literal and the text in the file is not equivalent. `$text` is already utf-8 (Тайна) and iconv does nothing to it. This is because you use [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) to put the actual binary value in the string. with the data in the file `\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0` is not escaped because it was read from a file and stored in a variable so its not a string literal. 
Try this to convert the data

```
$text = file_get_contents('log.txt');
$text = str_replace('\x', '', trim($text));
$text = pack('H*', $text);
var_dump($text);
```